# Solving the integral equation

Tags: differential-equations

Why does Wolfram Mathematica just rewrite my code instead of solving the integral equation? SigmaPhiBegin, SigmaPhiEnd are functions depending on Rho, Rho, bEnd, a, Kappa are constants. What needs to be corrected in the code so that it produces the result as in the analytical solution?

```
DSolve[{\[Sigma]PhiBegin[\[Rho]] == \[Sigma]PhiEnd[\[Rho]] - 
    Integrate[\[Sigma]PhiBegin[s]*(
      s*(a^2 - \[Kappa]*\[Rho]^2))/(\[Rho]^2*(a^2 + \[Kappa]*
          s^2)), {s, \[Rho], bEnd}]}, {\[Sigma]PhiBegin}, {\[Rho]}]
```

[image]

[image]
[image]

Comment: ...Either that, or the equation is not analytically solvable, or Mathematica doesn't know the solution, or it needs to be massaged into a form that Mathematica knows how to deal with.

Comment: @Mark I'm afraid your  analytical solution is wrong because `C` isn't constant, it is `C[\[Rho]]`!

Comment: I managed to get a solution and it coincided with my analytical solution. But maybe it can be improved somehow? Suggest your ideas please.

Public Link
https://www.wolframcloud.com/obj/04915df0-8d0c-4733-9a27-de1b56e80c73

Authenticated Link
https://www.wolframcloud.com/env/04915df0-8d0c-4733-9a27-de1b56e80c73